# Where I could find google maps' stylesheet

Tags: css, google-maps, stylesheet

I'm using osm maps with css files in my app (in iOS, but it does not matter) for customizing their appearance. I'd like to make them looks like google maps. Where I can find css or something like that for google maps? I need to know only colors of main highways and zones, so if you know them tell me)) thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you would have to dive into the Google Maps API to extract the kind of information you are looking for, I could be mistaken but Google does not offer a CSS way to manipulate its maps look and feel.

OR

Bring up a Google Map, take a screen shot and then use the eye dropper in your favourite graphics program to extract the HEX values.

Comment: yes, I was thinking the same way, but I haven't found some information about colors or widths of lines etc. Maybe my skills at searching are bad)) and you are right, manual extracting it from screenshots is the solution, but it is the last thing I will try

Comment: accepting it as I have not find it, and i've got it manually :)